# Preg_match when data is displayed using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, preg-match

I've been using a simple php script with `preg_match()` to pull data from an external site. The site has now changed the way it displays data and displays it using javascript, and I'm guessing you need different techniques to pull the data then?

To give you an example of the site layout it is basically something like

```
Nokia 5/300
Samsung 200/300
Iphone 544/2000
```

Before I just did preg_match Nokia to display the amount of Nokias left in stock on my own site. But since it is now displayed with javascript how would I go about to extract the Nokia data?

Comment: `str.match(regexp);`- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: Can you give a better code-sample, of how the code looks and what exactly you want to extract? `5` from `5/300` if preceded by `Nokia` ?

Comment: The entire Nokia line, and only that line :)

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
$str = 'Nokia 5/300 Samsung 200/300 Iphone 544/2000';

preg_match('/nokia/i', $str, $matches);

$nokia = $matches[0];
```

**JavaScript**

```
var str = 'Nokia 5/300 Samsung 200/300 Iphone 544/2000';

var matches = str.match(/nokia/gi);

var nokia = matches[0];
```